# Symfony2: What's the equivalent to PHP's explode() function in twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am fetching some results from database through doctrine.

The resulting array for e.g. `ads.attraction` has strings (words) with commas inside.

How can I separate each word from the comma and display each of them on it's own line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## solution:

The twig **[split filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html)**  converts a string to an array by given delimiter.

Afterwards you can output each element of this array using a `for` loop.

## example:

```
{% set array = "one,two,three"|split(',') %} 

{% for element in array %}
    {{ element }}<br /> 
{% endfor %}
```

Just replace `"one,two,three"` with your variable (`ads.attraction`) in your concrete case.

Comment: Thanks.... i just came over to update the answer for any one to find and you had it here. I was browsing the twig documentation while waiting for some one helpful like you to reply to my questing and found out about split there. Thanks any ways....appreciate it.